# ActionScript code not work

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have code below in first frame on layer actions but its not working.

How do I get it to work, what I am doing wrong?

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;

stop();

exit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onButtonOver);
exit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onButtonOut);
exit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClicked);

function onButtonOver(event:MouseEvent):void
{

}

function onButtonOut(event:MouseEvent):void
{

}

function onButtonClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
{
var btn:MovieClip = event.target as MovieClip;
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
}
```

Comment: You need to be far more descriptive about your problem. Are you getting errors? If not, what isn't happening that you're expecting to happen?

Comment: I got this error: Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 26 1120: Access of undefined property NativeApplication.

Comment: And code below does nothing: stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;

Comment: most likely `exit` is null.  Try doing `trace(exit)` right after you're stop()

Comment: @MattiKiviharju `Access of undefined property NativeApplication` means  the actionscript compiler hasn't found a definition of the `NativeApplication` class. Check this: 1. If this is an AIR (not a Flash Player) project in the publish settings (and if it's not make is so). 2. Add an import at the top of your code: `import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;`

Comment: Now I get error: Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 3 1172: Definition flash.desktop:NativeApplication could not be found.

Comment: Is this an AIR project? `NativeApplication` is only available for AIR applications. It is not available for web SWFs

Comment: This is not AIR project it is desktop flash project and be not web SWF project.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't included the NativeApplication class in your code.

You must have to import the class.

Add the statement at the top :

```
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
```